# Excel VBA - categorising disparate timestamps into 10 minute brackets

Tags: vba, excel

Working on a dataset - sample here:

```
    Device Name | Time    | Time Bracket
    ID 1        |06:24:03 | 
    ID 1        |06:24:05 | 
    ID 1        |06:31:03 | 
    ID 1        |06:54:58 | 
    ID 1        |06:55:00 | 
    ID 1        |06:59:12 | 
    ID 1        |07:24:14 | 
    ID 1        |07:24:15 | 
    ID 1        |07:32:12 | 
    ID 1        |11:07:18 | 
    ID 1        |11:21:27 | 
    ID 1        |11:32:12 | 
    ID 1        |11:32:13 | 
    ID 1        |11:36:01 | 
    ID 2        |07:05:55 | 
    ID 2        |07:05:56 | 
    ID 2        |07:22:15 | 
    ID 2        |08:32:49 | 
    ID 2        |08:32:51 | 
    ID 2        |09:05:22 | 
    ID 2        |10:11:24 | 
    ID 2        |10:11:26 | 
    ID 2        |11:34:41 | 
    ID 2        |11:42:34 | 
    ID 2        |11:42:35 | 
    ID 2        |12:50:40 |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to fit each row into a timestamp aggregated column...

So for example, anything from 07:00:00 to 07:09:59 is covered in the bracket 07:00:00 in column 3, 07:10:00 to 07:19:59 would be 07:10:00, and so forth.

I couldn't think of a formula that would do this, so I took to VBA.

I understand that I'll need to iterate down column B, and for each, look at the value, and use a case statement to determine which it should go to.

Simply put, I don't want to create 24*6 = 144 case/if statements.

I want it to only look at the minutes value, then determine if it should be fit into one of 6 time brackets (*:00, *:10 etc.), and replace the hour with the hour that is read from the value.

So I tried to implement something like this:

```
    Sub time_cater()
    For i = 1 To Rows.count
    Select Case Range("Ci").Value
        Case "**:0*:**"
            'Range("Ci").Value = Range("Ci").SUBSTRING(**)+:10:00

    Next i

    End Sub
```

And obviously more there...

The issue is that I can't figure out how to achieve the substring part... If there isn't one, I guess I'll go and make 144 case statements, but there MUST be a more elegant solution.

Edit: I also am completely unsure if the Ci part will work... I want it to go through row C (it's C on my worksheet), and look at the number that the counter is.

I pass this to you, dear people of SO! Thank you all in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem might be. You want to have the "time bracket" in column C and this "time bracket" seems to be exactly the same as column B (the Time) without seconds. So, why don't you put into cell `C2` the following formula (copy it down) and your are done `=TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0)`? Or maybe I underestimate the complexity of this question?

Comment: Hey, below is the answer that I wanted. 
I don't think I was clear enough, but it's also because I didn't know that time manipulation with TIME(x) was possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this bracketing via an Excel function knowing the data in column B is a DateTime. The way I would do it is something along the lines of:

```
=HOUR(B2) &"_"& INT(MINUTE(B2)/10)
```

That will create brackets you can use for filtering / sorting.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Bloody Hell, that's a clever way of doing it...! Seems there's a tonne about Excel I don't know yet! 
Used a slightly modified version that populates the 0s etc. and it works!
        =IF(HOUR(B4)<10, "0", "")&HOUR(B4)&":"& INT(MINUTE(B4)/10)&0&":00"

Comment: I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep yet, but thank you!

Comment: :) - My pleasure and glad it worked, @R.Sama. And, as for not knowing enough about Excel yet - Keep asking questions. We're glad to help and point you in the right direction! Good luck with your project.